# Set variable in select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Raw data:

[image]

This what I want:

[image]

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @BAL DECIMAL(38, 2) = 1000

SELECT
    ID
    ,CASE WHEN [TYPE] = 'CREDIT' THEN AMT ELSE 0 END CREDIT_AMT
    ,CASE WHEN [TYPE] = 'DEBIT' THEN AMT ELSE 0 END DEBIT_AMT
    ,CASE WHEN [TYPE] = 'CREDIT' THEN AMT + @BAL ELSE AMT - @BAL END BAL
FROM
    @TB
```

My problem I cannot `SET @BAL += AMT or @BAL -= AMT` inside the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: If you want to assign a variable inside a `select` then you can only assign variables i.e. you cannot mix assignment and recordsets. But otherwise you just use `select @Bal = @Bal + Amount` or whatever your calculation is.

Comment: As per the  [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your SQL Server is 2012+, you can try this:

```
DECLARE @BAL DECIMAL(38, 2) = 1000
DECLARE @TB TABLE (ID INT, TYPE varchar(100), AMT money);

INSERT  @TB
    VALUES  (1, 'CREDIT', 10),
            (2, 'DEBIT', 15),
            (3, 'DEBIT', 5),
            (4, 'CREDIT', 20),
            (5, 'DEBIT', 10)

SELECT  ID,
        CASE WHEN [TYPE] = 'CREDIT' THEN AMT ELSE 0 END CREDIT_AMT,
        CASE WHEN [TYPE] = 'DEBIT' THEN AMT ELSE 0 END DEBIT_AMT,
        SUM(CASE WHEN [TYPE] = 'CREDIT' THEN AMT ELSE -AMT END) OVER(ORDER BY ID)+@BAL as BAL
FROM    @TB
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: I use SQL Server 2016, but this is not what I want. I don't know what I should tell in English. You can see my 2nd picture above.

Comment: Explain:
1000 + 10 = 1010,
1010 - 15 = 995,
995 - 5 = 990,
990 + 20 = 1010,
1010 - 10 = 1000

Comment: @Sophairk your picture above doesn't explain why you are using a variable? If you just want that as a resultset you don't need a variable?

Comment: @Sophairk,  according to your comments, I corrected my code.

Comment: @Максим Золотенко Thank you so much!

Comment: @Dale K SELECT @ BAL  = BAL FROM @ TB WHERE TR_DATE =  DATEADD(DAY, -1,GETDATE())